# Control strong DC motor with microcontroller

Tags: avr, dc-motor

Could anyone explain to me what it takes to control a strong DC motor with e.g. an AVR?

For example if I have a 24V Motor with 5A or more. How can I build such a circuit? Especially if I want to change the direction that the motor is running (H bridge).

Answer (score 3):

You answered your own question; you'll need an H-Bridge. [Here's a DigiKey listing](http://www.digikey.com/product-search/en?FV=fff40027%2Cfff802d2%2C2040002%2C2040005%2C2040009%2C204000e%2C2040011%2C2040012%2C2040015%2C2040050%2C2040056%2C20400c4%2C20400d0%2C2040102%2C2040119%2C2040158%2C2040309%2C2040433%2C2040480%2C204049b%2C20404b2%2C20406fa%2C2040757%2C4500096%2C4500121%2C4500164%2C4500208%2C4500307%2C4500332%2C45003af%2C45004c8%2C450055e%2C45005bc%2C1a000003%2C1a000005%2C1a00000b%2C1a000016&mnonly=0&newproducts=0&ColumnSort=1000011&page=1&stock=1&pbfree=0&rohs=0&quantity=1&ptm=0&fid=0&pageSize=25) of H-bridges that are rated for at least 5A, and for supply voltages at least to 24V, sorted by price ascending. The [Infineon BTM7700G](http://www.infineon.com/dgdl/BTM7700G_DS_10.pdf?folderId=db3a304412b407950112b408e8c90004&fileId=db3a304316f66ee80117642f65ef6a96&ack=t) in that list is relatively inexpensive and exceeds your requirements by a healthy safety margin -- and, since it's a 1.27mm pitch SO package, it's extremely easy to solder.

Comment: One caveat : While the Infineon part exceeds his stated requirements, it may not meet his actual requirements which are not so clear. A "5A" rated motor may have a stall current of 30A or more, which won't do a 9.5A bridge much good... On the other hand if 5A is actually the stall current rating, then it'll be fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can buy a ready made H-Bridge board which will handle 5A or more.

For example look at ebay, or your favourite supplier, and search for BTS7960B H-bridge. That claims to handle upto 43A. It is available for less than 10GBP.

The datasheet for the part is at [BTS79608 at infineon](http://www.infineon.com/cms/en/product/power/motor-driver/integrated-half-bridge-driver/BTS7960B/productType.html?productType=ff80808112ab681d0112ab6ce42009ac)

The BTS7960B is a discontinued part, which is probably why it is so cheaply. 
It is okay for a one off or a small number of near-future projects, but not such a good choice for a product or long term projects.

Infineon have newer parts, but I haven't seen ready made boards for such a good price.

There are a couple of ways to drive H-Bridges.
One approach is feed it:

1. a PWM signal to control the motor speed,
2. a direction signal, which determines which side of the H-bridge is
   High, and which is Low and hence sets the direction power flows through
   the DC motor
3. An enable signal, which switches the power to the H-bridge on and
   off. This is used to stop the motor (slowly)

There are other approaches, for example feeding two PWM signals in, one to each half of the H-Bridge, and by adjusting the relative ratio of PWM you could determine both direction and speed.

If you *want* to design it 'from scratch' and use less sophisticated components, then a straightforward way to get started is to build the two H-Bridges using N-Channel MOSFETs for the low-side (tied to ground), and P-Channel MOSFETS for the high-side (tied to e.g. 24V).

Then use a MOOSFET driver (lots of comapnies make these, e.g. Micron, Microchip, etc).
These will take the PWM signals from the Arduino, and handle switching both the low-side and high-side MOSFETs. You could just about prototype this on a breadboard using through hole parts.

Part cost might be under 10GBP

Again, you would feed it PWM signals. Depending on your choice of MOSFET driver, you might also need to give it enable signals. Having separate enables for each MOSFET is a 'good thing', because you can get more control over the motor.

The disadvantage of this simple approach is the integrated circuit will have *much better* protection circuits inside.

If you search the web, you are likely to find a few other manufacturers that produce H-Bridge components (other than infineon), for example Allegro, ST Micro, Texas Instruments.

I would tend to use a ready made H-Bridge, or half H-Bridge as it will be much quicker to get it working, and likely has better built-in protection.

Comment: I absolutely second the ready made option. There's no valid reason to do something that's already integrated on a silicon chip in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Depend if you need speed control. If not, use of solid state relay module or mechanical relay/contactor is popular choice in industrial machine control setting, especial with large motors of hundreds to thousands watts.

Answer (score 0):

Also check into motor speed controllers used for radio control hobby, so called "ESC". High current, some are high voltage too. Control speed using PWM signal from mpu.